# Unauthorized users can create tasks, how to remove this feature?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I hid the form of adding tasks from unauthorized users, but they can still create a task via the address bar, how to prevent this?

Thank you.

```
class Api::V1::HolidaysController < Api::V1::BaseController
  skip_before_action :doorkeeper_authorize!, only: :index

  expose :holiday,  -> { Holiday.find(params[:id]) }
  expose :holidays, -> { Holiday.all }

  def create
    return render_api(holidays, :created) if holidays.create(holiday_params)
    render json: { errors: holidays.errors.messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

  private

  def holiday_params
    params.require(:holiday).permit(:name, :date)
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you want to authenticate user before create action?

Comment: They must be authorized users if they can create tasks through this controller, because you already have `doorkeeper_authorize!` for authorization and they are passing it.

Comment: I want only registered users to create a task. Right now by sending manual request I'm able to create a holiday. Back-end doesn't check user for that type of action. And how do I fix this?

Comment: Can you post your `Api::V1::BaseController` code as well?

Comment: Thank you all, the problem was that my colleague was wrong, everything works fine.